# Need help publishing to ROS topics from a 2nd machine

Tags: ros, network

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I just added a 2nd machine to my ROS network and went through all of the appropriate tutorials on making sure the two could ping each other ( http://wiki.ros.org/ROS/NetworkSetup#Configuring_.2BAC8-etc.2BAC8-hosts).  On my second machine i have exported the master URI and can echo ros topics running on the master just fine.  When i try to publish onto a new topic from the second machine, the master can see the new topic exists, but if i try to echo it the master is unable to receive any information.

This forum seemed to address my exact problem, (http://answers.ros.org/question/90536/ros-remote-master-can-see-topics-but-no-data/).  They suggest adding the master computer to the etc/host file on the 2nd machine.  My problem now is that i can't seem to properly edit the etc/host files!  Can anyone provide a good tutorial on how to do this? I have tried several different ways and i'm sure i'm not doing it properly.  **<--edit 7/10/17: I'm led to believe this is not the real issue. See edit below**

Thanks!

**EDIT: Okay i have editing the /etc/host file and can now successfully ping the host machine from the 2nd machine via its alias.  I can also export ROS_MASTER_URI=alias:11311 and can access the ROS network from the 2nd machine.  Still have the same problem though: 2nd publishes to a new topic, master sees new topic, but when master echoes new topic nothing is received**

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/265862/need-help-publishing-to-ros-topics-from-a-2nd-machine/) by [Ryan_F](https://answers.ros.org/users/31057/ryan_f/) on ROS Answers with karma: 71 on 2017-07-09

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Ed Venator](https://answers.ros.org/users/2636/ed-venator/) on 2017-07-09**:
"My problem now is that i can't seem to properly edit the etc/host files!"

Can you elaborate? How are you trying to edit `/etc/hosts`? What happens?

**Comment by [Ryan_F](https://answers.ros.org/users/31057/ryan_f/) on 2017-07-10**:
I think i got it to work since i can now ping the master from the 2nd machine via its alias, and can also export ROS_MASTER_URI using the master alias. So editing the /etc/hosts file may not be my problem anymore. I will update my question to reflect this. Thanks

**Comment by [gstavrinos](https://answers.ros.org/users/27452/gstavrinos/) on 2017-07-11**:
You need to edit the /etc/hosts file for both machines!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

My problem turned out to be that i was exporting the wrong ROS_IP address on the 2nd machine.

After editing the /etc/hosts file on the 2nd machine to include the host machine, and exporting the ROS_MASTER_URI=http://hostalias:11311 (on the machine not running roscore) you need to export the proper ROS_IP's on BOTH machines so ROS knows where to listen.  To do this:

1. Identify the IP address of each machine
2. export ROS_IP=ipaddress  of each machine in any terminal you use to communicate with ROS.  Make sure that you are exporting the IP address of the respective machine.  My problem was that i was exporting the host computer's IP address in both machines!

After taking those steps you should be able to both publish, and subscribe to topics from a 2nd machine.

Hope that helps!

---

Originally posted by [Ryan_F](https://answers.ros.org/users/31057/ryan_f/) with karma: 71 on 2017-07-11

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

In order to be sure that your machines can communicate successfully, I would advice to also export the ROS_IP parameter in each machine's .bashrc.

Regarding your question on how to edit the /etc/hosts file, it is simple as just running: `sudo nano /etc/hosts`

---

Originally posted by [gstavrinos](https://answers.ros.org/users/27452/gstavrinos/) with karma: 641 on 2017-07-10

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Ryan_F](https://answers.ros.org/users/31057/ryan_f/) on 2017-07-10**:
I always export the proper IP in every terminal i open.  I have also made sure i reset the DNS after and i still have the same issue.  2nd machine publishes to a new topic, master sees the new topic but when "echoed" nothing is received. 2nd machine can also ping master via its alias.